# Macbook 15(Mid 2015) gets loud using android studio

Tags: android

could anyone who are using macbook 15 retina mid 2015 tell me if your gear gets really noisy when coding in Android Studio? I use default display mode and I use Darcula as the theme~ It's weird as soon as I start coding in android studio it gets loud but everything's fine otherwise. Thanks a lot~

Comment: It's absolutely normal.

Comment: I have a macbook pro from 2011. That problem happened to me when loading some sites containing Flash. A remarkable problem I had was that the Mac restarted alone when using the Android emulator while watching a youtube video with Safari.

Comment: It's a relief hearing the word 'normal' from you guys... I think intel i7 makes awful lot of heat than i5 because I've asked my friend who uses mbp 13 i5 and he doesn't seem to have the noise problem... so...probably I should just make do with it...

Comment: The MacBook I used restarted when I'd use emulator plus a site that contains Flash.

Comment: Solution : [Here link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986498/android-studio-using-100-cpu-at-all-times-no-background-processes-appear-to)