# Android Studio 2.1.2 regularly uses up to 100% of disk for more than 2 minutes

Tags: android

I have a dell alienware pc with 32gb of Ram ,8 3.2gz cores and 4 drives of which Drive C: is an SSD.
The laptops primary function is android coding.

Often without warning Studio will become unresponsive completely and mouse clicks etc all go ignored. during this time Drive D: disk utilization is at 100%. [image: disk at 100% - this is not the SSD drive just a regular spinning one]

Note that this is not even during app building or running on device, just regular tabbing within the app or highlighting a block of code.
I have screen shots of this.

I have searched for weeks and updated my SSD drivers to the latest, i removed windows prefetch , stopped Windows search indexer etc but nothing works. 
Also this only happens with Android studio and i've not seen this with any other app.[image]

Does anyone have this issue and is there a  solution?

Comment: I am running 2 Android studio's and 2 PHPStorm's at the same tame among some other things, and CPU usage is 15%, Memory 50%. I have i5 with 16 gigs of ram. Dunno what might be causing this for you (I go no SSD either).

Comment: Take a look at this post: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986498/android-studio-using-100-cpu-at-all-times-no-background-processes-appear-to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986498/android-studio-using-100-cpu-at-all-times-no-background-processes-appear-to)

Comment: +Vucko and Reenactor Rob, Thanks for checking out my question. I had actually already seen the article and tried invalidating cache and reducing heap size even though my issue was with the harddisk and not CPU. Doesnt seem to be GIT either because i've not wired up any version control system in my studio. (had bitbucket previously but after an update it doesnt work either so i removed the plugin)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After studying the issue for some time it seems the culprit behind 100% disk usage is NOT Android Studio but instead BitDefender Security Service. The interaction with Android studio is causing 100% Disk utilization on the files used by Studio even though i have whitelisted Studio in Bitdefender.

Thanks to anyone who attempted or even thought about this issue in the view to help.

Comment: what did you do about it ? Even whitelisting doesn't help in 2023.

Comment: I switched to Microsoft Defender and dropped all third party antivirus. So far it's been ok. Not sure if that might work for you though, given it's so drastic. I got tired of fighting with the third party tools.

Answer (score 6):

The high disk usage is because your antivirus is scanning android studio files in real time. 
Here is what I've done:

- I disabled Windows Defender. I'm using another antivirus.
- In the configuration of my antivirus I've added exceptions for all the android studio folders (android folder, android studio folders, gradle folders etc)

It works far better now.

Comment: i kept windows defender, but added the exceptions you mentioned, and things seem to work fine as well.