# Why does my CPU utilization gets to 100% when I open Android Studio?

Tags: performance, android-studio

The Title is 70% of the total context here, even though I have Ryzen-5 7th gen and 16gb ram which are more than the specified requirements, but when I open android studio the CPU utilization in the task manager shots up to 100% than after 10 seconds comes to normal.

Is there something more to the android studio that I don't know or is that just normal?
I had tried to open the app with all unnecessary background processes closed but still it shot up to 100%.

Thank you for your time and effort

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986498/android-studio-using-100-cpu-at-all-times-no-background-processes-appear-to

Comment: Does [Android studio using > 100% CPU at all times - no background processes appear to be running](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19986498) solve your problem?  You mention CPU usage dropping again after 10 seconds, but that doesn't, so perhaps it's a different problem.  If it turns out to be a different problem, we can reopen this question.